# Prolog Same Expression but different result

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I wrote the following code but need help:

```
kip(A,B) :- A#= 2*B.

?- kip(100,L).

L=50
```

I wrote almost the same thing differently:

```
kip_v1(A,B) :- A#= (B+1)*(B+1) - B*B -1.
```

`(B+1)*(B+1) - B*B -1` is `2*B` is same for `kip` but this does not give `50`:

```
?- kip_v1(100,P).

P+1#=_G12699,
P+1#=_G12711,
P^2#=_G12723, 
_G12699 in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
_G12711*_G12699#=_G12753,
_G12711 in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
_G12753 in 101..sup,
101+_G12723#=_G12753,
_G12723 in 0..sup.
```

Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: What I've found is that SWI seems to require, in the second case, that you limit the domain. If you use the default where max is `sup`, you get "arguments not sufficiently instantiated" on the query: `100 #= (B+1)*(B+1) - B*B - 1, label([B]).`. However, if you use, `B in 0..100, 100 #= (B+1)*(B+1) - B*B - 1, label([B]).` you will get `B = 50`. I tried the same query in GNU Prolog and I did not need to limit the domain in that case. Interesting results which I can't explain at the moment.

Comment: does prolog solves an expression or to solve expression wants real value? for example does it give  2*a+1 from (a+1)*(a+1)-a*a , or should we give some value to a to find result

Comment: Prolog does not automatically simplify the expression. (Also note you mean `2*A + 1` not `2*a + 1` since `a` is not a variable.)

Comment: what about :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
    abv(A,B) :- A#= (B+1)*(B+1)-(B*B)-1. it correctly works for ?- abv(A,4).
A = 8. but not abv(8,R). what should i do?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my first comment, you can limit the domain of `R`: `R in 0..<something>` followed by `abv(8, R)`.

Comment: abv(A,B) :- A#= (B+1)*(B+1)-(B*B)-1, B in 0..55.  this also did not worked. @lurker

Comment: In my comment, I suggested putting the `B in 0..55` *before* the expression. Also, you'll need `label([B])` at the end. Please refer to my first comment for details.